# How know if migrate Wubi to partition is successful

Tags: wubi, migration

I run this script 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MigrateWubi

and reveiced a message :

```
Found Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (12.04) on /dev/sda7
...
 migration completed successfully.
```

Then i restarted computer and choose ubuntu from 2 lines

```
Windows 
Ubuntu
```

. But i don't see what changed, if i am on a partition with Ubuntu or Wubi .

***@ubuntu:~/sudo fdisk -l***

```
/dev/sda1   *          63   167782859    83891398+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2       167782860   976768064   404492602+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       167782923   284337032    58277055    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda6       587224008   669566016    41171004+   7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       284340224   587223039   151441408   83  Linux
/dev/sda8       669569024   710529023    20480000   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

EDIT: I download proposed pack from issue 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a terminal (ctrl-alt-T), type

```
mount
```

If you see that your root directory ("/") is mounted on something like "/dev/sda7", then your installation is on that partition. If in doubt, post the result of that command here.

If mount shows something like

```
/dev/loop0 /
```

it means that you did not manage to install the grub loader correctly, and you still use the Windows loader to get to the WUBI installation.

Follow [these](http://alexsleat.co.uk/2010/03/11/howto-reinstall-grub-using-ubuntu-live-cd/) instructions to install grub.

1. Make sure that on /dev/sda7 you have the copy of the system (you can use the LiveCD to boot the system that is installed on /dev/sda7 to see whether it was installed correctly)
2. Given that your new system is mounted in WUBI /dev/sda7 on /media/ce0c18e4-3d5d-466b-ba64-e19f1b129957, run

   ```
   sudo grub-install –-root-directory=/media/ce0c18e4-3d5d-466b-ba64-e19f1b129957 /dev/sda
   ```

This should install Grub to /dev/sda and allow you to boot in Ubuntu.

Comment: i installed it on /dev/sda7 . This is result when i run "mount" : https://gist.github.com/d76146ca58d7d570ebe5

Comment: Means that you are still running WUBI. You did not manage to install grub correctly.

Comment: Did `wubi-move-2.2.sh` help me to install it ?

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: I get error `More than one install_devices?` when run `sudo grub-install –root-directory=/media/ce0c18e4-3d5d-466b-ba64-e19f1b129957 /dev/sda`

Comment: My bad! Omitted a dash in the --root-directory option and grub-install did not recognize it. I edited the command line above, can you try it again?

Comment: Hi, i will try it in tomorrow, now i can't use that computer .

Answer (score 0):

If you used `--no-bootloader` when you ran the script, you can boot the migrated install from the Wubi grub menu. I am assuming this is what you did, because otherwise it would have install Grub2's bootloader to /dev/sda and the first thing you would have seen was a grub menu (not the Windows boot manager, which you described).

You'll see the migrated install around the 4th option in the menu, after `Previous Linux versions`. Boot it from there before trying to install Grub to the bootloader. Then you can confirm it's working and just install grub from there:
`sudo grub-install /dev/sda`

If you don't see the Wubi grub menu, then say so (it sometimes happens and setting the grub graphics mode to `text` in the wubi install will fix this).

Here's an example of my Wubi grub menu with the migrated install as the 4th entry (**not** the highlighted entry):
[image]